# How do I exclude video podcasts from my podcast smart playlist

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I created a Smart Playlist to sync to my iPod Touch so I can listen to my podcasts one after the other while I'm on a long drive.
[image: Smart Playlist]

I can't figure out how to leave Video Podcasts off that list, though.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `Kind contains 'audio'`should do the trick. At least it's what I'm doing and it works.
`Kind contains 'video'` will give you the video Podcasts.

Comment: Actually, "Kind contains 'video'" misses some that have a Kind of "Quicktime movie".  I added "Kind contains 'video'" OR "Kind contains 'movie'" and it seems to be working now.